# Как во Flutter выровнять текст в строке по высоте?

Tags: flutter

Как  во Flutter выровнять текст в строке по высоте? На нижеприведенной картинке видно, что второй текст выше чем первый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если установить параметры: **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline**
То выровняться по низу. А вот как выровнять по верху?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код к вопросу нужно прикреплять кодом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема по-простому в том, что есть высота самого текста, а есть высота линии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для подобных случаев с текстом есть специальный виджет `Baseline`:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(
      '00',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 70,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    Baseline(
      baseline: 0,
      baselineType: TextBaseline.ideographic,
      child: Text(
        '00',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Всегда старайтесь избегать хардкод решения симптомов проблемы.